# How can I find available ip ranges in a gcloud VPC?

Tags: gcloud, google-vpc, google-datastream

I have to specify a subnet in order to allow Google's Datastream to connect with a source database but every single subnet I specify gives me the error:

```
Error: Error creating PrivateConnection: googleapi: Error 400: The IP range specified (10.<number>.<number>.0/29) overlaps with a reserved IP range. Provide a different IP range.
com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: <eye3 title='INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: The IP range specified (10.<number>.<number>.0/29) overlaps with a reserved IP range. Provide a different IP range.
```

It would be helpful to find out all the reserved ip ranges so I can avoid them but I don't think that is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Console GUI shows networking [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list) which shows details on IP address allocation to each subnet.

The CLI command will show you details on networking [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/subnets/list):

```
gcloud compute networks subnets list
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496397/8016720) for more details on reserved IP addresses that also might affect you.